# Is mongoengine with numeric keys possible?

Tags: python, python-3.x, mongoengine

I have mongo-documents with structure like this

```
{
   "_id":{
      "$oid":"5ea6c61c8a94f7c75e426669"
   },
   "title":"The title",
   "attributes":{
      "5e733c347e6caf0a4d643e7f":[
         "5e7b1e62bf924d3a5ed181de"
      ],
      "5e733c6c7e6caf0a4d6443c8":[
         "1"
      ],
      "5e73697aabee30028e573c4d":[
         "5e7cc610654336666131866f"
      ]
   },
   "id":"5e7fc2426a499664e15de014"
}
```

Is it possible to map fields names like "5e73697aabee30038e573c0d" with mongoengine?
These variants are not working

```
class attributes(EmbeddedDocument):
    5e733c347e6caf0a4d643e7f = list()
```

```
class attributes(EmbeddedDocument):
    '5e733c347e6caf0a4d643e7f' = list()
```

I've found a solution for me. I have to use *db_field* parameter:

```
class attributes(EmbeddedDocument):
    field_name = ListField(db_field='5e733c347e6caf0a4d643e7f')
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've found a solution for me. I have to use db_field parameter:

```
class attributes(EmbeddedDocument):
    field_name = ListField(db_field='5e733c347e6caf0a4d643e7f')
```

Answer (score 1):

Can you elaborate on the structure of your mongo documents. It seems to me that you are using mongoid as values. There is a neat way to do it. You can use ReferenceField.
Example :

```
class user(Document):
 #define all the values you want here

class attributes(Document):
   attrib=ReferenceField("user")
```

This type of structure helps when you have a long lists of embedded documents in the collection and makes it easier to search and perform other work on the database.